# Использование функции flush

Tags: c++

Что конкретно делает функция `flush()` из `basic_ostream<>`? Где и почему стоит её использовать?

Comment: А что пишут в референсе?

Comment: @free_ze что-то непонятное

Comment: @free_ze например, почему надо обязательно делать `flush()` перед `system()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `basic_ostream` есть буфер. Данные выливаются из него не все время, а порциями, по мере наполнения того самого буфера. Чтобы убедиться, что поток отдал все и ничего не оставил в буфере, его принутительно "сливают" раньше срока (`flush`).

`system` пишет в `stdout` и `stderr`, потому, если вы тоже что-то туда пишите своим потоком, нужно убедиться, что в буфере ничего не застряло перед вызовом `system`.

Comment: `system` ничего не пишет. Могут писать команды, которые вызываются через `system`.